# Loop table with checkboxes and get row values on jquery mobile 1.3

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I need to loop a table and get the row cells data to variables. I have no problem getting it to work (working fiddle here) http://jsfiddle.net/alsosun/8nvPX/3/

But when I switch to jquery 1.3 mobile, I get no values passed to the variables.

Been searching, but cannot find the difference. code:

```
<table id="one">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>System</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td>FSS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>87</td>
    <td>Harry</td>
    <td>MSS</td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

script

```
var stringresult = '';
$('#add').on('click', function () {
  $('input:checked').each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    var one = $this.parent().siblings('td').eq(0).text();
    var two = $this.parent().siblings('td').eq(1).text();
    var three = $this.parent().siblings('td').eq(2).text();
    alert(one + ' ' + two + ' ' + three);

    //or just 
    stringresult += $this.parent().siblings('td').text();
  });
  alert('This is the whole string: '+stringresult);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8nvPX/4/

Comment: just fluke--got it `$("input[name='case[]']:checked").each(function () { //closest("td").siblings("td"),
              
                  var code = $(this).closest("td").siblings("td").eq(0).text();
                  var out = $(this).closest("td").siblings("td").eq(1).text();
                  //var two = $(this).eq(1).text();
                  alert(code + " " + out)
              });`

Comment: @Omar just saw yours. Yes, that works thank you--add it so I can accept it

Comment: this is the correct one http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/j8jqV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop inside `tr`'s children (`td`) that doesn't contain an `input`, using `:not()` and `:has()` selectors.

```
$('#add').on('click', function () {
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        var checked = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:has(input))");
        $.each(checked, function () {
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/j8jqV/)**